# Strange computation times conditioning on ARefs

Tags: clojure

I have a function foo:

```
(defn foo [a b] (* a b)) ; <- 2 ms per 10K
(foo 3 8) ; <- 24
```

I want to be able to pass it agents, atoms, or refs as well.

```
(defn bar [a b] (* @a @b)) ; <- 3.5 ms per 10K
```

But then what about mixing literals and agents?

```
(defn aref? [x] (isa? (class x) clojure.lang.ARef))
(defn foo [a b] (let [a (if (aref? a) @a a)
                      b (if (aref? b) @b b)]
                  (* a b))
(def x (ref 3))
(def y (ref 8))
(foo 3 8); <- 120 ms per 10K
(foo 3 y); <- 71 ms per 10K
(foo x 8); <- 73 ms per 10K
(foo x y); <- 6 ms per 10K
```

But those are some *really* funky running times. I tried changing the order of the branching in `foo`, and that apparently has nothing to do with it. Why does my new `foo` take 20 times longer to evaluate over literals than over ARefs?

Comment: I am guessing that the performance characteristics of isa?are similar to those of Java's instanceof. instanceof performs worse when the answer is false. If classes are not identical it has to examine superclasses, implemented interfaces and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In effect as ez121sl mentioned the performance differences come from the use of `isa?`. Looking at its source code you'll find that it uses a built-in `global-hierarchy` (if none is provided) and recursively checks if any the `bases` (base classes) of the `child` class is the `parent` class defined.

The use of `instance?` (which uses Java's `instanceof?` behind the covers) results in times that are more sensible.

```
(defn aref? [x]
  (instance? clojure.lang.ARef x))

(defn foo [a b] (let [a (if (aref? a) @a a)
                      b (if (aref? b) @b b)]
                  (* a b)))
(def a (ref 3))
(def b (ref 8))
(time (dotimes [i 10000] (foo a b))) ; ~ 9ms
(time (dotimes [i 10000] (foo a 8))) ; ~ 2.7ms
(time (dotimes [i 10000] (foo 3 b))) ; ~ 2.7ms
(time (dotimes [i 10000] (foo 3 8))) ; ~ 1.7ms
```